# Storing pointer to functions in a map

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, stdmap

Can anyone explain why this piece of code is generating the error as shown below. I am trying to store pointer to function in a map. The code would work fine if I keep everything in main() function. Also I would appreciate it if someone shows how to fix it.

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace boost;
class obj {
public:
    int num1;
    int num2;
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
};
typedef boost::variant<int, float, double, std::string> MultiType;
typedef MultiType(*FnPtr)(obj);

        
        
class c {
public:
    MultiType add(obj o);
    std::map<std::string, FnPtr> metricToFuncMap = { { "i", add } };
};
MultiType c::add(obj o) {
    { MultiType x;  x = o.num1 + o.num2; return x; }
}

int main() {
    obj o;
    //add
    MultiType d;
    d = 1;
    o.num1 = 1;
    o.num2 = 2;
    //concat
    o.s1 = "hello";
    o.s2 = "world";
    c c;
    MultiType x = c.metricToFuncMap["i"](o);
    std::cout << get<int>(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
E0289   no instance of constructor "std::map<_Kty, _Ty, _Pr, _Alloc>::map [with _Kty=std::string, _Ty=FnPtr, _Pr=std::less<std::string>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const std::string, FnPtr>>]" matches the argument list
```

Comment: `MultiType add(obj o);` is a non-static member function, which works completely different from regular function (pointers). You probably want to make it `static`

Comment: `&add` has type: `MultiType (c::*)(obj)` not `MultiType(*)(obj)` (AKA `FnPtr`).

Comment: It would be better if you use `std::map<std::string, std::function<MultiType(const obj &)>> metricToFuncMap`, then you can use lambda or bind.

Comment: @MarekR Can you please show it how I should modify my code above. I would appreciate it. I came across std::funciton and bind, but was unable to use it in the code above. I was getting weird errors. Thanks

Comment: I'd probably just use a `std::map` of [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly minimal example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}
};

typedef std::function<std::string (const Foo &)> MyFunction;
typedef std::map<std::string, MyFunction> MyMap;

int main(int, char **) {
    Foo foo;
    MyFunction f = [](const Foo &) { return "Hello"; };

    MyMap myMap { {"x", f} };

    MyFunction blah = myMap["x"];
    std::cout << "Got: " << blah(foo) << "\n";
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ g++ --std=c++17 Blah.cpp -o Blah && Blah
Got: Hello
```

The advantage of using std::function is that while there's a little overhead, it's far more powerful. You can (as I have) used lambdas. Your lambdas can capture `this`, meaning you can call non-static member methods. You can also use `std::bind()`, if you prefer, although I don't care for the syntax and will usually use a lambda instead.